# Adapt ColorFunction in Array Plot

Tags: plotting, color

The problem I'm facing is how to adapt `ColorFunction` so that it ranges from green (low values) to red (high values):

```
ArrayPlot[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}, ColorFunction -> (* ??? *)]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}], 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Green, Red}, #] &)]
```

[image]

If you need to specify a more specific range of colors:

```
ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}], 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{0, Darker[Green]}, {.25, Green}, {.5, 
 Yellow}, {.75, Orange}, {1, Red}}, #] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what I've been looking for. thx

Comment: @rainer glad to help

Comment: If the points are equispaced, as in `Blend[{{0, Darker[Green]}, {.25, Green}, {.5, Yellow}, {.75, Orange}, {1, Red}}, #] &`, one can just give the list of colors to `Blend[]`: `Blend[{Darker[Green], Green, Yellow, Orange, Red}, #] &`.

Comment: @J.M. you're right, I just wanted to show how the blending can be adapted for special cases.

Answer (score 8):

This works:

```
ArrayPlot[Array[BitXor, {64, 64}, {0, 0}], ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[#, 1 - #, 0] &)]
```

[image: red-green array plot]

---

Here's a little utility function for automatically generating a color function that linearly interpolates between two colors:

```
linearColorFunction[colMin_?ColorQ, colMax_?ColorQ] := 
      Function[Evaluate[RGBColor @@ Chop[Expand[{1 - #, #}.
               (List @@@ ColorConvert[{colMin, colMax}, RGBColor])]]]]
```

Examples:

```
linearColorFunction[Green, Red] (* OP's example *)
RGBColor[1. #1, 1. - 1. #1, 0] &

linearColorFunction[Cyan, Magenta] (* "cool" colormap in MATLAB *)
RGBColor[1. #1, 1. - 1. #1, 1.] &
```

As already noted, the function generated by `linearColorFunction[colMin, colMax]` behaves the same way as the function `Blend[{colMin, colMax}, #]`.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some data:

```
data = Table[x + Sin[3 x + y^2], {x, -3, 3, .01}, {y, -3, 3, .01}];
```

In Mathematica there are designated so called [**Color Schemes**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ColorSchemes.html). For example in your case you could use "RoseColors":

```
ArrayPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "RoseColors"]
```

[image]

But I personally would go with "TemperatureMap" as good indicator of low/high values. Another way to is to use `Hue` with modified argument to get green-red for start-end of the scale:

```
ArrayPlot[{Range[0, 1, .01]}, AspectRatio -> 1/4, ColorFunction -> (Hue[.8 (# + .3)] &)]
```

[image]